# Show that an operator has closed graph

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a multiplication operator $A_g$ in $L^2$
$$A_gf=gf$$
with
$$f\in D(A)\Leftrightarrow \|fg\|_{L^2}<\infty.$$

It's easy to see that the domain is dense in $L^2$. I need to show that the graph of the operator is closed in the direct sum space of $L^2$.

But how to show this? The domain is dense so that if we take $f_n\rightarrow f$ for some $f\notin D(A)$, doesn't this show that the graph is open?

Comment: What assumptions do you have on $g$?

Comment: @cmk it is in the domain.

Comment: @cmk Sorry, actually there is no restriction besides $g$ being complex valued and measurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to show is that if $(f_n)$ is a sequence in $D(A)$ such that $f_n\rightarrow f$ and $A_g f_n\rightarrow h,$ then $f\in D(A)$ and $A_g f=h.$ Since you're just asking for a hint, recall that $L^2$ convergence gives a subsequence that converges pointwise almost everywhere. You can directly use this to get both facts simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks, what was the other fact?

Comment: By facts, I meant ($1$) $f\in D(A)$ and ($2$) $A_gf=h.$

Comment: Ok, but how do we get to $||fg||_{L^2}<\infty$, where $f_{n_k} \rightarrow f $ a.e.? Also does this not imply that $L^2=D(A)$, a bit weird?

Comment: $1.$ Apply the result that I mentioned to $A_gf_n,$ instead. $2.$ It does not, and it's not hard to think of counter-examples. If you take an arbitrary $f\in L^2,$ it need not be the case that $fg\in L^2.$ Why do you think that? It is dense, but they're not equal.

Comment: so if we take $f_n\rightarrow f$ s.t. $fg\notin L^2$, how can $f\in D(A)$?

Comment: Because we don't just know that $f_n\rightarrow f$. We also know that $A_gf_n$ converges.